# Mysql get one row by using group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have A and B two tables in my mysql database.

```
create A (
    id    int  primary auto_increment,
   ....
);
create B (
    id    int,
    status int default 0, /*only between 0 and 2*/
   foreign key (id) references A(id) ,
   index `index_test`(id, status)
);
```

Now, I want to get info view from A and B.

```
create view info 
    as
    select A.id, statistics.status, statistics.status_statistics as ss
        from A
        left outer join (
             select id, status, count(*) as status_statistics
                  from B
                  group by(B.id, B.status)
        ) as 'statistics' on (A.id = statistics.id);
```

But, this will get Multi-row result rather that one. How to get One?

For example:

```
table A:
id
--
1
2

table B:
id status
------------
1     0
1     1
1     2
1     0
2    1
```

I use the above method, I will get:

```
id status ss
-----------------
1   0    2
1   1    1
1   2    1
2   1    1
```

Howerver, I want to get:

```
id | column_name_one | column_name_two | column_name_three
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 2 1 1
2 0 1 0
```

Comment: @RaymondNijland thanks a lot

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application level code.

Comment: @Strawberry thanks for your suggestion, I will consider it.